# Bootable USB burning Problem

Tags: usb, iso, burning

I am trying to burn 19.04 latest verified ISO on 2 different USB Flash drives but during installation, after creating partitions I found error that "your DVD/Flash Drive has not burnt fine, Please burn it on Lower X speed".

But my ISO File, USB Flash drives, Hard Disk etc everything is ok. I have tried it on another PC but get the same error. I Burn USB Flash Drive using Rufus and have tried old and newer versions many many times.

I download Fedora 29 ISO and burnt that to the same USB and that worked, installed well, no problem.

Comment: Try different install images: network installer, or server image. If you choose server image, you can easy turn it to desktop by installing gui: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` [link alternative-downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Comment: [This tutorial might help.](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)

Comment: How are you verifying that the ISO you have is good? If the drive is good, and Fedora's ISO can boot, that suggests the image is bad, perhaps even at the source you're getting it.